# jQuery Tablesorter plugin is off by one column

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I have a table made sortable by column using the jQuery tablesorter plugin.  I'm using Mottie's fork (http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) but I was previously using the original version and had the same problem: when I click on a `<th>` element, the next column to the right is sorted.

I had to create a custom `textExtraction` method, and I think this might be my issue.

```
$('#sort_this').tablesorter({
    textExtraction: {
        function(node){
            return $(node).nextAll('td').find('input').val();
        }
    }
});
```

Perhaps `nextAll()` is not the right method to use here (I'm finding the documentation unclear).  Should I be using a different selector or is my problem elsewhere?

Comment: What did you expect nextAll('td') to do in this case? I don't think it actually makes any sense to use it here. isn't `node` a td?

Comment: You're right.  It somehow escaped me that the node was a td (not sure what I thought it was).  Removing that part solved my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Although, `.nextAll('td')` would only work if node was a td, but it's still weird.